# What happens if member functions of a class in a header file are implemented in two cpp files?

Tags: c++, compilation, header-files

What happens if member functions of a class in a header file are implemented in two cpp files which are both compiled by the compiler? I mean, lets say I have this code:

```
//header file A.hpp

class A
{
 public:
    int funcA();
}

//implementation file A1.cpp
#include "A.hpp"
int A::funcA(){/* whatever*/}

//implementation file A2.cpp
#include "A.hpp"
int A::funcA(){/* whatever*/}
```

Will the compiler trigger an error?

Comment: This would be a violation of the [one definition rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60085469/why-does-the-one-definition-rule-exist-in-c-c)

Comment: ... and a violation of the ODR is Undefined Behavior.  No error from the compiler is required.

Comment: This would be a linking error, if you attempt to link with both definitions. If you only link with one of them, there is no issue.

Comment: *Will the compiler trigger an error?* **No**.   There are many situations that are ill-formed code, where the compiler is not required to warn about the problem (**no diagnostic required**).  On some systems, the **linker** may warn about the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What happens if member functions of a class in a header file are implemented in two cpp files which are both compiled by the compiler?

It would be [Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior), as defined by the [one definition rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60085469/why-does-the-one-definition-rule-exist-in-c-c).

> Will the compiler trigger an error?

No.  A compiler's job is to compile a **single** translation unit (a cpp file) and neither of your translation units violate this one definition rule.

The linker *might* inform you, but it is not required to do so.  In the case of gcc, for example, ODR violations are only reported when link-time optimization is enabled.